# clang-format 3.8.1 fails with "Assertion failed: getClient() && "DiagnosticClient not set!""

Tags: windows, git-bash, clang-format

I'm running clang-format 3.8.1 on Windows through git-bash with the line:

```
find . -iname *.h -o -iname *.cpp -iname *.c | xargs clang-format -i
```

but it keeps failing:

> Assertion failed: getClient() && "DiagnosticClient not set!", file D:\src\llvm_package_3.8.1-final\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Basic\Diagnostic.cpp, line 363
>   0x000000013FFC26A6 (0x0000000000000016 0x0000000189CC4301 0x0000000000000000 0x00000000771A7E0A)
>   0x00000001400DB32D (0x0000000100000001 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 0x0000000140159EE4   0x0000000000000260)
>   0x00000001400DB638 (0x000000014018B270 0x0000000140159EE4 0x000000014015A3B0 0x0000000140159EE4)
>   0x00000001400D9857 (0x0000000000000000 0x000000000000000F 0x000000000000004F 0x0000000000000000)
>   0x000000013FFF5D3C (0x0000000000CB29BA 0x0000000000CB29BA 0x0000000000C2C940 0x0000000000CB29B8)
>   0x00000001400379BD (0x0000000000BF9530 0x000007FE00000000 0x000000000E00020C 0x00000000771CF2D3)
>   0x000000013FFB3D37 (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000338 0x0000000002520B80 0x0000000000000000) 0x000000013FFB1DD6
>   (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000)  0x00000001400DA2F0 (0x0000000000000000
>   0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000)
>   0x0000000076F759BD (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000), BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0xD bytes(s)
>   0x00000000771AA2E1 (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000), RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x21
>   bytes(s) xargs: clang-format: terminated by signal 4

The same error is listed in [LLVM assertion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455630/llvm-assertion-error) but that's for a build and there's no helpful answer. Is there a simple way to get round this?

Answer (score 0):

because you path is not correct， it include other file， change your path to source code path.

```
find .(change here) -iname *.h -o -iname *.cpp -iname *.c | xargs clang-format -i
```